# What does the word "fixed" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I was reading feedback about the television show *Survivor*, and some people wrote that this show was "fixed". I could not understand or make a guess what they meant.

I searched on the Internet but I did not find any example or definition, either. Can you tell me its definition and when I can use it?

Comment: -1 Voting to close as GR.

Comment: Meaning of [fixed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fixed?q=fixed#fixed__7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a synonym for "[rigged](http://www.wordnik.com/words/rig)" in this sense.

> Rig: v. To manipulate dishonestly for personal gain. "The judges rigged the boxing match so *Slow Foot Joe* would win.

They're saying that Survivor, a supposedly *authentic* survival program, is planned in advance, perhaps scripted, to look more interesting, to create more conflict, to induce more horrified reactions from the viewing audience, etc.

Technically, it is, but the usage of fixed implies that the fixing is done at the cost of the show's authenticity.

Comment: Why *rig* when *fixed* is defined? http://english.stackexchange.com/a/92708/14666

Answer (score 1):

You could have searched in a dictionary too :)

[Fixed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fixed):

> (of a sports contest) having the **outcome dishonestly predetermined**:
>   *the fight’s fixed—the ref has your card marked*

You can use it to refer to any contest which has had its "outcome dishonestly predetermined". It can be used in relation to everything from elections to beauty pageants. A related term is [price-fixing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/price-fixing?q=price%20fixing).

Comment: "I searched on the Internet" -- "in a dictionary too": dictionaries, too, are on the Net! So, GR.